# Correct type to represent the size of a pointer in C?

Tags: c, c99

Of course I could just do something like

```
sizeof (void *);
```

But I feel as would I have read of a type that is only given for presenting the address spectrum by ISO/IEC9899.

Something like `ptrdiff_t`.

The problem is, I'm using a va_list and don't know what type the pointer is of.

So I would prefer a general pointer type instead of something specific as `int *` or `char *`

My code looks like:

```
void param_exec (tmp, ...)
{

    va_list vlArgList;
    void *szArgLocation;

    va_start (vlArgList, tmp);
    szArgLocation = va_arg (vlArgList, void *);
    va_end(vlArgList);

    return;
}
```

It feels quite wrong just using `void*` but is there another, more fitting type?

Could anyone name me that type (if there is one)?

Comment: This isn't clear. `sizeof(T*)` is the correct way to get the size of that pointer. `ptrdiff_t` exists because the difference of two pointers is *not* a pointer, and so can't be stored in a variable of pointer type.

Comment: and what would I do if I can't target `T` as it is address of a va_list?

Comment: `sizeof` can also operate on expressions.

Comment: @Zaibis Edit your post, and add the problem code there. It is hard to figure out what your problem is and why `size_t` doesn't suffice.

Comment: My problem ist, I just know the size of the types I get, I don't know what type they are off. So it feels wrong doing sizeof (void *) as it is most time something like `char *` or `int *` But I can't know. So what would be the best styl?

Comment: I agree with @user; please add a concrete code example that we can discuss.

Comment: Are you asking which type can hold the value `sizeof(void*)` (which is any integral type, on a sane platform, but `size_t` is guaranteed to) or which type is the same size as a void* i.e. for which T is `sizeof(T) == sizeof(void*)` guaranteed?

Comment: I'm asking for a type thats equal to sizeof (void *).

Comment: Now that you've added code, it seems that your question is really "is void* really the correct type to hold the value of an unknown pointer type?".

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth Now as you say it that way... yeah that was my question. I'm sorry if I asked in wrong words.

Comment: In which case, the answer is "yes, except in the case of function pointers".

Comment: @user694733: That's incorrect. The `va_arg` macro takes a type name as its second argument. That can be any pointer type (among other things). `void*` is distinct from other pointer types.

Comment: Note that you need to specify a type for your parameter `tmp`, and `tmp` is very seldom a good name for a parameter.  I think `void *` is as good a type as any for a generic (data) pointer.  To improve on it, you'd have to explain how it is going to be used — and the sample code doesn't use the value.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: But you need to know the type of an argument to a vararg function, doing `va_arg(args, void *)` on an `int *` is UB, strictly speaking.

Comment: The arguments to your `param_exec` function can be of just about any time you like. Decide what the type should be, document it, require callers to pass arguments of that type, and use that type in your invocation of the `va_arg` macro. If `void*` makes sense, use that. If some other type makes sense, use it. We don't have enough information to determine what type makes sense for your function.

Comment: @KeithThompson The point is, It is intendet to be an SQL API, so it could be of any type to data which the user want to store, but I can't exactly figger out from intern `param_exec`

Comment: @mafso: You're right, it probably is UB.  That means that if your variadic function is designed to take `void *`, the caller would need to explicitly cast each of their arguments, I guess.

Comment: @Zaibis "I'm asking for a type thats equal to sizeof (void *)" - the concept of a type being equal to a number makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Zaibis: Every expression and value in C has a specific type. `void*` is *probably* appropriate for what you're doing, (it can hold a converted value of any pointer-to-object type), but you haven't given us enough information to be sure. I don't know what you're going to do with these parameter values or what a call might look like. And immibis is quite correct: "a type that's equal to `sizeof (void*)`" makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that you expect a pointer but you don't know what it points to, do use a `void*`. That is precisely what a `void*` is meant to be used for, to pass around black box pointers where the user code is supposed to ensure that it makes sense.

As to the size of a pointer, you can store it pretty much in everything. Currently, the size of a pointer is 4 or 8, and it will take some centuries until it reaches 256. So, even using a single byte to store the size would be sufficient for a very long time.

Answer (score 3):

Ajay pretty much nailed it. Look at [**Important Data Types**](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Important-Data-Types.html). Your choices are `ptrdiff_t` for **signed integer type of the result of subtracting two pointers** and `size_t` for **an unsigned integer type used to represent the sizes of objects.**  The only other caveat is:

> **Compatibility Note:** Implementations of C before the advent of ISO C generally used unsigned int for representing object sizes and int
>   for pointer subtraction results. They did not necessarily define
>   either size_t or ptrdiff_t. Unix systems did define size_t, in
>   sys/types.h, but the definition was usually a signed type.

Comment: Pre-ISO implementations are almost certainly not worth considering these days.

Comment: Anyway, thats not what my question was about.

Answer (score 1):

The value of [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) operator should be stored in a variable of type `size_t`. It is used to determine the size of an object or a type in bytes.

Comment: That is absolutly not my question.

Comment: My question is, what type is representing the processorwidth, and is meant by the standard, for represnting the size of the pointer type in generall. not what is the return val of sizeof();

Comment: @Zaibis The answer is `size_t` again.

Comment: @ajay: in practice, yes. In theory, pointer sizes can vary (in particular object pointers vs function pointers).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes. The C standard also says `sizeof` operator may not be applied on function pointers.

Comment: @ajay: it says it can't be adopted to objects of function type, not that it can't be applied to function pointers.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: That's because there are no objects of function type.

Comment: @Zaibis: Your question title is "Correct type to represent the size of a pointer in C?". `size_t` is the correct answer to that question. But I don't see how the body of your question relates to the title. The correct type to represent the size of any object or type is `size_t`. For example, `sizeof (void*)` is of type `size_t`, and typically has a value like `4` or `8`. It's not at all clear to me what you're trying to ask. Are you asking about a type to hold the *value* of a pointer rather than the *size* of a pointer? See also the comment I just posted on the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson: So in practice, it's fine!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Um, what's fine?

Comment: @KeithThompson: If there are no objects of function type, then there's no chance that you could apply `sizeof` to something invalid.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: For example, `sizeof main` is a constraint violation.